# O(1) complexity array access

Tags: algorithms, database, search

I have an array of heights, with irregularly spread stations, e.g.: `arrH=[100 500 1000 2500 4500]`. During run-time I receive some height, h, and I need to determine which cell (index) contains the closest height to h. E.g.: `h=720 -> arrH[1]`.
I can do any pre-processing, build any dictionary/hash table in an offline-mode.
Is there a possibility to achieve O(1) during run-time?
Thank you!

Comment: Is it safe to assume this array of heights is known at compile time, and is never, ever going to change during run time? (if so this sounds doable)

Comment: The array is constant, but it's loaded from a file at construction of the main system class, so it's unknown during compilation.

Comment: you can get log(n) easily with a search tree....

Comment: you can also quite easly get log(log(n)) which is cool....

Comment: Any explanation about log(log(n))?  :)

Comment: @AK_ how do you get log(log(n))?

Answer (score 4):

If the maximum value is reasonable, then you could do it with a lookup table of length N where N is the maximum value in the array.  So, for example, your array looks like this:

```
[2,5,6,9]
```

Then you create an array that looks like this:

```
[0,0,0,1,2,2,3,3,3]
```

Lookups in that array is O(1)

Obviously this assumes that you will have many lookups without the array changing as I think array creation should be O(N) * O(Log(N)).

Comment: I believe array creation is just O(N). At worst, it seems you'd need to do a couple of passes over the starting array.

Comment: The maximal value can be about 200,000. But I have also another arrays, who's values can be negative, and another one with maximal value that is "reasonable" with your definition. As I said before, during system's start up, I have plenty of time to create any other helpful arrays or tables.

Answer (score 4):

In the general case (that is, where Steven Burnap's small-max-height assumption doesn't hold, or alternatively where you have to accommodate floating-point values as inputs), I believe the answer to your question is no. You're describing a single pass through an algorithm that populates a histogram with nonuniform bins. (For a discussion of various tradeoffs in histogram construction, see [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15707064/efficient-histogram-implementation-using-a-hash-function).)

The naive implementation of a histogram-population algorithm with nonuniform bins known in advance runs in O(log n), with n the number of bins, which is equivalent to the length of `arrH` - this is simply binary search.

As the link above suggests, though, interpolation search will allow a best-case time of O(1) and an average time less than O(log n). Moreover, depending on how nonuniform your bin distribution is, you could achieve best-case results a large proportion of the time.

On the other hand, because "constant" doesn't necessarily mean "small", you could very well wind up doing better with the naive binary search if `arrH` is relatively small or your bin distribution is particularly pathological. The inflection point where interpolation search begins to do appreciably better would need to be determined via profiling.

Long story short: binary search - O(log n) - may be the best you can do, but take a look at interpolation search. Which is better will depend intimately on your data.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed explanation! How do I obtain O(1) in the case of uniformly spread stations?

Comment: Broadly, you'd construct your histogram bin edge array, divide the value to be tested by the bin size, floor it, and use that to index into the array.